# Maximum value of the difference

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, maxima-minima

If $g\in C^1(IR) $ , and $x\leq y$ , such that $g(x)=x$ and $g(y)=y$. Let for some $c\in[x,y]$, such that $|g'(c)|<0.75$. Find the maximum value of $|y-x|$

> What I have tried:

Firstly I tried to apply LMV theorem ,
$g'(c)=\frac{g(y)-g(x)}{y-x}=1$ , but which is not fit with the condition $|g'(c)|<0.75$.

Secondly I just put all the conditions in wolframalpha, I saw a 3D plot there in which I see the maximum value of both $y$ and $x$ are $1.5$ and their minimum is $0$. But I think this one may not be correct.

And, furthermore I think LMV theorem is not applicable here, due to $g\in C^1(IR)$, and sorry to say even I don't know what does this represent. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: One can create a smooth $g$ such that $g(z) = z$ for $|z| >1$ and $[0,1] \subset g'([-1,1])$ in which case one can choose $|y-x|$ as large as one wants.

Comment: @copper.hat can you please show your work as a solution.. and can explain the domain of g what is meant by IR. Thanks for your reply

Comment: I presume IR is $\mathbb{R}$, a notation for the reals.

Comment: Then what is C ? If it is meant to be real and why is LMV theorem invalid

Comment: The notation $C^1(A)$ describes the set of continuously differentiable functions with domain $A$. In this case $A$ is the reals.